# Github Action for Azure Webapp: Failed to fetch credentials from Publish Profile

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

[image]

I'm getting the error on the above screenshot while Deploying the Azure WebApp to Azure by GitHub Actions.
I have tried disconnecting and connecting the WebApp multiple times. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Go to WebApp in Azure Portal and download publishing profile.You would get someting similar to the below.

   ```
   <publishProfile profileName="[app-name] - Web Deploy" publishMethod="MSDeploy" publishUrl="waws-prod.publish.azurewebsites.windows.net:443" msdeploySite="[app-name]" userName="$[app-name]" userPWD="***" destinationAppUrl="http://[app-name].azurewebsites.net" SQLServerDBConnectionString="" mySQLDBConnectionString="" hostingProviderForumLink="" controlPanelLink="http://windows.azure.com" webSystem="WebSites">
       <databases />
   </publishProfile>
   <publishProfile profileName="[app-name] - FTP" publishMethod="FTP" publishUrl="ftp://waws-prod.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net/site/wwwroot" ftpPassiveMode="True" userName="[app-name]\$[app-name]" userPWD="***" destinationAppUrl="http://[app-name].azurewebsites.net" SQLServerDBConnectionString="" mySQLDBConnectionString="" hostingProviderForumLink="" controlPanelLink="http://windows.azure.com" webSystem="WebSites">
       <databases />
   </publishProfile>
   <publishProfile profileName="[app-name] - ReadOnly - FTP" publishMethod="FTP" publishUrl="ftp://waws-prod.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net/site/wwwroot" ftpPassiveMode="True" userName="[app-name]\$[app-name]" userPWD="***" destinationAppUrl="http://[app-name].azurewebsites.net" SQLServerDBConnectionString="" mySQLDBConnectionString="" hostingProviderForumLink="" controlPanelLink="http://windows.azure.com" webSystem="WebSites">
       <databases />
   </publishProfile>
   ```
2. Change the publishing url at the first publishing profile for Web-Deploy to `[appname].scm.azurewebsites.net` instead of

   `waws-prod.publish.azurewebsites.windows.net`
3. Go to Github and go to the repository.
4. Go to the respective workflow yml file in .github/workflows and look for `${{ secrets.<SECRET_NAME> }}`. Remember the `<SECRET_NAME>`.
5. Go to settings > secrets and click on 'update' button respective to the secret name you remember from above step.
6. Paste the XML code inside Value and click 'update secret'.
7. Go to 'Actions' and select the failed workflow run and click 're-run jobs'.

Now your Web Zip Deploy should be succesfull.

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but if my app is called `example-app` do I set `[example-app].scm.azurewebsites.net` or `example-app.scm.azurewebsites.net`?

Comment: @Zal you should use example-app.scm.azurewebsites.net

Comment: After testing it looks like it's `[example-app].scm.azurewebsites.net`

Comment: +1 for sure. But I had no idea why default value doesn't work. It was generated in Azure Deployment card.. It is so confusing..

Answer (score 1):

For my case, i would like to add to the above answer that you need to add an app setting called WEBSITE_WEBDEPLOY_USE_SCM and set true. (I am using linux for my app service) and get publish profile.
You will notice that the publish profile will automatically change waws-prod.publish.azurewebsites.windows.net to [example-app].scm.azurewebsites.net.

**TLDR;**

1. Set **WEBSITE_WEBDEPLOY_USE_SCM** = **true** in app settings
2. click on get publish profile button to get an updated publish setting.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this issue while deploying a NextJS application using GitHub actions.

The issue occurred after I had renamed the Azure App Service for the application. So when I try to deploy the app I get the error:

```
deploy
Deployment Failed, Error: No credentials found. Add an Azure login action before this action. For more details refer https://github.com/azure/login
```

**Here's how I solved it**:

All I had to do was:

- Go to the Azure App Service page on the Azure portal
- Under the Overview section, clicked on **Download publish profile** to download the new publish profile for the renamed application
- Next, I added the new publish profile in the GitHub Actions workflow to replace the old one.
- Finally, redeployed the application and it worked absolutely fine.